# Siunitx and breqn causes repeated value and unit error in align

Tags: siunitx

I am experiencing a weird bug when using `\SI{}{}` inside a align block.
The following latex code results in the value and unit being repeated as seen on the picture.
But only when written inside a align block.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\centering
\SI{311.2}{\radian / \second}
    \begin{align}
        f_{n} &= \SI{311.2}{\radian / \second} \nonumber \\
        &= \SI{49.5}{\hertz}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

I have not experienced this kind of behaviour on another machine and even in another document on the same machine.

What could cause this behaviour?
And what can i do to stop it?

**EDIT 1**: Adds a complete example.

In construction of the example i figured out that it is the package `breqn` which causes the error.
But then i would like to ask, why does this happend, and what can i do about it?

Also, I have updated the title of the question to reflect change in question.

Comment: works fine for me. Show a complete example.

Comment: All works fine here: can you add `\listfiles` to your input and then edit the `File list` from your `.log` into the question?

Comment: I think the general consensus nowadays is the you should not use `breqn`, the idea is nice, but in reality, its goal is very very hard to achieve and as such it is incompatible with a lot of stuff.  Since we are seeing things four times, I'm guessing it is messing with `\mathchoice` or similar (which basically has to typeset everuthing 4 times before it knows which is is being used)

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior too. You might want to consider using `\per` instead of a `/`. I think it works better, but it's your choice. If you want to show a slash instead of negative exponents within the units, you can add the option `\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}` or `\SI[per-mode=symbol]{}{}` for a single unit. See the `sinunitx` package manual for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In construction of the example i figured out that it is the package `breqn` which causes the error.